# Tensorflow 2.0: Cannot Import tf.keras.utils.conv_utils

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using **Tensorflow v2.1.0** which is compiled from source. How can I import any function from `conv_utils` module? E.g. `convert_data_format()`, `conv_output_length()`, `normalize_tuple()`, etc.

I wanna create my own convolution/pooling layer. "Everything" almost looks different when I wanna migrate from `import keras` to `from tensorflow import keras`.

This is what I did

```
> python -c "from tensorflow.keras.utils import conv_utils"                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'conv_utils' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils' ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer! The second answer although with fewer upvotes is the more updated.

Comment: Will probably test it when I get the chance. It did not solve my problem back then. If someone could confirm the solution for me, I'll accept it right away.  So, people can gain a benefit from it.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import conv_utils
```

Comment: I'm very glad to know that you are interested in my problem... But I'm very sorry to say that I've done it before. The strange thing is I could only import it that way in the python interactive shell, but get an error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'` if I run my `.py` file. So do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Look at the answer just below. the new way is `import tensorflow.keras.utils as conv_utils`

Answer (score 2):

This is the new way to import conv_utils in Tensorflow 2.1.0:

```
import tensorflow.keras.utils as conv_utils
```

Comment: Sorry, but this way has given me `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'conv_output_length'`