# How to use conv_utils in Keras 2.4.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In older versions of keras (such as 2.2.4), `conv_utils` could be imported with

```
from keras.utils import conv_utils
```

After trying to find out how to import this module in newer versions, an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067176/tensorflow-2-0-cannot-import-tf-keras-utils-conv-utils) helped me to import it as

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.utils as conv_utils
```

But there are some functions from the older `conv_utils` that cannot be used from `tensorflow.keras.utils` such as `deconv_length` or `normalize_tuple`, and if I run `dir(conv_utils)` these functions are not there:

```
>>>dir(conv_utils)

['CustomObjectScope',
 'GeneratorEnqueuer',
 'OrderedEnqueuer',
 'Progbar',
 'Sequence',
 'SequenceEnqueuer',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '_sys',
 'custom_object_scope',
 'deserialize_keras_object',
 'get_custom_objects',
 'get_file',
 'get_registered_name',
 'get_registered_object',
 'get_source_inputs',
 'model_to_dot',
 'normalize',
 'pack_x_y_sample_weight',
 'plot_model',
 'register_keras_serializable',
 'serialize_keras_object',
 'to_categorical',
 'unpack_x_y_sample_weight']
```

Comment: Latest `tf.keras.utils` version has all the functions what you have mentioned above. Thanks!